# How to stop time interval in my function?

Tags: javascript, intervals

I have this function:

```
function timedFunction(functionString,timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout(functionString+"timedFunction(\""+functionString+"\","+timeoutPeriod+");",timeoutPeriod);}
```

This function me call:

```
 timedFunction("startStopky();",1000);
```

startStopky(); is a function that I want in a specified time interval repeatedly run. Everything works excellently, but if I want stop this interval, I have to stop as follows:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
            window.clearInterval(i);
        }
```

Unfortunately this will stop all intervals, and I want to stop just one particular. How can I do it?

Comment: Don't pass strings to setTimeout/setInterval. To stop a specific timer, *save the timeout/interval ID* so that it can be used later to refer to the specific timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing recursive calls to `timedFunction` just do:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(startStopky, 1000);
```

and to clear it just do:

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setTimeout` function returns a timeout ID that you use with `clearTimeout` to remove that timeout. The same goes for intervals but in that case it's a `setInterval` and `clearInterval` combo.

E.g.:

```
var t = setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000);
clearTimeout(t);

var i = setInterval(yourFunction2, 500);
clearInterval(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a Timeout, but you are clearing an Interval. `clearInterval` clears intervals, not timeouts.

You want [`window.clearTimeout(timeoutId)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout)

If you want to stop a single one, you use the processId of that interval.

```
window.clearTimeout("13");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that both `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` can be used to clear either kind!

Comment: Pointy, this might be true, but unless it belongs to their respective official specification i would not rely on it.

Comment: @Sebas Oh yes I agree; it's just an oddity that I stumbled across a couple years ago.

Comment: @Pointy, not all browsers treat them the same. I rather be safe than sorry. I know most modern browsers treat them to be. Drives me bonkers, if IE only did it, people would be screaming bloody murder. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using strings to do this:

```
function timedFunction(fn, interval) {
  var timerHandle;

  function runIt() {
    fn();
    timerHandle.id = setTimeout(runIt, interval);
  }

  return timerHandle = { id: setTimeout(runIt, interval) };
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var handle = timedFunction(startStopky, 1000);
```

To stop the process:

```
clearTimeout(handle.id);
```